# How to find the latest email ID in Gmail via Gmail API

Tags: javascript, api, gmail-api

I wanted to know ho to find the latest email ID in Gmail via Gmail API.
I can get a list of all emails, get a specific email by ID, but I need the latest email.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Make question more precise please.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages

Comment: I need to get the body from the latest received email via Gmail API

Comment: I wanted to know the way to find the ID of the latest email so I can get the body message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) returns messages in the the order of the last one that arrived.  by adding max-results you can get only a single record back.

```
function listMessages(userId, query, callback) {
  var getPageOfMessages = function(request, result) {
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      result = result.concat(resp.messages);
      var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
      if (nextPageToken) {
        request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
          'userId': userId,
          'pageToken': nextPageToken,
          'q': query,
          'maxresults': 1,
        });
        getPageOfMessages(request, result);
      } else {
        callback(result);
      }
    });
  };
  var initialRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
    'userId': userId,
    'q': query
  });
  getPageOfMessages(initialRequest, []);
}
```